# Understand limit voltage and current

Tags: voltage, switches

It could sounds odd but I am trying to find a switch for my inverter that is an isolator.

My batteries are 12 V and my inventer can do over 5 KW, but I found a switch at 48 V, rated 300 A.

If I use it on 12 V what would be the max rated current for it?

Comment: the voltage rating has nothing to do with the current rating ..... the 48V voltage rating means that, when the switch is open, then 48V across the contacts will not cause an arc to form .... higher voltage could cause an arc across the open contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 5KW inverter the max current would be:

5000W/12V = 416A

The current rating should be somewhere in the manual also. So if you really are trying to switch all the batteries at the same time, 300A may not be enough to handle the 400Amps that potentially could be run across the switch. Find a better switch.